# Unable to insert caluclated field in PIVOT TABLE created using win32COM python library

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I am trying to insert a calculated field in PIVOT TABLE created using win32com python library. But when i execute my code excel gives me error "**References, names and arrays are not supported in Pivot Table formulas**"

```
import win32com.client
Excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
win32c = win32com.client.constants
Wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open('MyWorkbook')
Excel.Visible = True
Ws = Wb.Sheets('PR Jan20')

Wb.Sheets.Add()
Wb.ActiveSheet.Name = 'PivotSheet'
WsP = Wb.Sheets('PivotSheet')

MaxR = Ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
MaxC = Ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
C1 = Ws.Cells(1,1)
C2 = Ws.Cells(MaxR, MaxC)
PivotSourceRange = Ws.Range(C1,C2)

PCache = Wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=PivotSourceRange,Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)
PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=WsP.Range('B2'), TableName='RegisterPivot', DefaultVersion=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

PTable.PivotFields('Party').Orientation = win32c.xlRowField
PTable.PivotFields('Party').Position = 1
PTable.AddDataField(PTable.PivotFields('Gross Kgs'))
PTable.AddDataField(PTable.PivotFields('Amount (RS.)'))
#till above this line code is working fine

#this below line is causing issue
PTable.CalculatedFields().Add('Average Purchase Rate', '= Amount (RS.) / Gross Kgs')
```

['Excel Error'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFfqL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the above issue. The problem was with the column name "Amount (RS.)" i renamed the column to "Amount" and everything worked fine. I think VBA is not comfortable with () parenthesis in Pivot Field name.